# how to create a yii model without a database table

Tags: php, yii

i created a yii model that has no database table, but the problem now is, whenever I tried to call the model function within a view file, it doesn't get recognize

```
class blah extends CActiveRecord()

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{UNVETTED}}';
    }

    public function sayHello()
    { 
         echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

while inside the view i called it like this

`blah::model()->sayHello()` , and then I got a white page of death, why is that?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to create Yii model without a table it can be created using  `CFormModel`. You have define model variables, their rules and attribute label.

Example code of a Change Password Form created using CFormModel.

```
<?php

class ChangePassword extends CFormModel 
{

    public $password;
    public $verifyPassword;
    public $currentPassword;    

    public function rules() {

            $rules[] = array('currentPassword', 'safe');
            $rules[] = array('currentPassword', 'required');            
            $rules[] = array('password, verifyPassword', 'required');
            $rules[] = array('verifyPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' =>'password', 'message' => 'Retyped password is incorrect');

            return $rules;
    }

    /**
     * Declares attribute labels.
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
            return array(
                    'password'=>'New password',
                    'verifyPassword'=>'Retype your new password',
                    'currentPassword'=>'Your actual password',
            );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You dont need to use [`CActiveRecord`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord) if your model is not associated with a database table. Use [`CModel`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel) or [`CFormModel`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormModel) instead

BTW, fix this:

```
class blah extends CActiveRecord()
```

to

```
class blah extends CActiveRecord {
```

I think that's why you are getting a white page.

Comment: is it ok to not implement the rules() ?

Comment: you still can to it since rules method is CModel's: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#rules-detail Whether it's ok or not to have validation rules on your model, - well, - you decide :)